# How to show a Moodle plugin only to specific users

Tags: plugins, moodle

My team has developed a Moodle plugin (as a new type of Moodle assignment) and it works OK. Now, we want to install it in our university official Moodle server. The administrators of that server asked us that our plugin, at least for some months (beta stage), should be only shown in specific courses of the platform and for doing that, the filtering code should be -at least in the beta stage- hardcoded in our plugin.

Apart from disliking to hardcode anything, I am wondering if that is possible at all, I mean, can our plugin filter itself from the dropdown list where all the assignment type are shown to the courses' teachers in Moodle? If not, can our plugin filter itself so that it only works in some specific courses (and shows some sort of "not available" message for others)?

If we were free of any restriction, what would be the best/recommend approach for accomplish this filtering feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use capabilities and roles. Here is a quick off the top of my head solution.

In your access file

```
/mod/yourmodname/db/access.php
```

Add an add instance capability, something like

```
$capabilities = array(
    'mod/yourmodname:addinstance' => array(
        'riskbitmask' => RISK_XSS,
        'captype' => 'write',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_COURSE,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
        ),
        'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/course:manageactivities'
    ),
);
```

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Activity_modules#access.php

You will need to bump the version number in version.php to install the capability.

Then define a role for "beta course creator" based on a editingteacher maybe? in site admin -> users -> roles or go straight to /admin/roles/manage.php

And add the capability created above to the beta course creator role.

Then assign the role to teachers who are in beta.

Then users who have that role can add the plugin to a course.